# Iterate Object only printing values

Tags: javascript

when i execute following code:

```js
var myObj = 
  
{
    "name": "moose",
    "age": "22",
    "friends": "0",
  
};
for (x in myObj) {
    console.log(x);     
}
```

I get following output:
`{"name":"moose","age":"22","friends":"0"}`

But I only want the values, in order to stringify them afterwards.
I tried `console.log(Object.values(x))` but it didnt work out.
Desired output:
`moose, 22, 0`

Thanks in Advance

Comment: _"I get following output: `{"name":"moose","age":"22","friends":"0"}`"_ That's not true as you can see in the interactive code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate through all the keys of a **JS** Object, use the below syntax:

```
for (var key in myObj) {
    if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key);
      }
 }
```

So that you can print your values as requested with:

```js
var myObj = 
  
{
"name": "moose",
"age": "22",
"friends": "0",
  
};

for (var key in myObj) {
    if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(myObj[key]);
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to access your object with x key to access x value:

> myObj[x]:

```js
var myObj = {
    "name": "moose",
    "age": "22",
    "friends": "0", 
};

for (x in myObj) {
    console.log(myObj[x]);     
}
```